# Store email template variables not working

Tags: expresso-store, html-email

I'm using Expresso Store 1.6.5. and I'm having trouble with the order email templates that get sent out to buyers.

I would like to include variables like {you_save},{you_save_percent},{sale_price},{promo_code_value},{promo_code_type} and a few others. Ideally I would also include product photos as well as a link to the products themselves but it's not a huge deal...but for some reason those variables aren't appearing. They are wrapped inside an {items} tag but I still can't get them to show up. I've checked the documentation and it says they should be available. I've also tried wrapping the items tag around an exp:channels tag and still nothing.

Does anyone have a more complex e-mail template with this kind of information? Am I missing something obvious

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to wrap order specific tags (promo_code, order_total, etc) within the items loop as they won't show up.

To get custom fields in your email templates you will need to pass the entry_id to a channel entries tag and then have order specific items outside of the items loop

```
{items}
  {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {custom_image_field} - {price} - {title}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/items}

Promo Code: {promo_code}
Order Total: {order_total}
```

Comment: just tried it but I still can't get the following variables to work:

{you_save}
{you_save_percent}
{sale_price}
{promo_code_value} (the regular promo code variable works)


the promo code value variable is outside the items loop while the others are inside just like in your example